# Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator can't create an internal switch

Tags: visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

When I try to run Visual Studio 2015 Android Emulator device I get the following errors:

System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost in in Faulted State

XDE Exit Code: CouldntCreateInternalSwitch (16)

When I try to create an internal switch for my adapter manually I get a general Access Denied Error (0x80070005) (even while trying to do it with elevated permissions)

Trying to start the virtual device from command prompt shows **errorlevel 9009** (Microsoft site says 9009 = DNS server not authoritative for zone).

My Windows user account is present in Hyper-V administrators group.

I tried switching from wireless network adapter to cable LAN, didn't help.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by uninstalling drivers of all network adapters (then obviously the system restored them...)